# New object is not defined due constructor being inside another function

Tags: javascript, constructor

**My problem:** I cant have my reference to the constructor being defined when I create a new object being the constructor is deeply nested inside 2 functions:

Func1 - Func2 - constructor inside Func2.

It seems I have some issues with the concept of returning. Is my problems something we call "closures"? Anyways it works when I create my new object inside the function that holds my constructor but not one level higher.

---

**What I am trying to achieve:** I want to be able to create a new object even it the constructor is inside various nested functions.

I would appreciate some insight. I am a purely visual learner so examples are welcome.

---

This is how my constructor looks like:

```
function breakpoint(init) {
    this.condition = (function init() {
        if (Math.abs( browser.width - cached.previousWidth) >= 100 && browser.width < 800) {
            elem.style.fontSize = Math.floor(result - 50) + 'px';
            cached.previousWidth = browser.width;
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the full code in Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hkqxswed/1/

Comment: No object is returned from `breakpoint` ? See `console` at jsfiddle `Uncaught ReferenceError: breakpoint is not defined ` . What is expected return value from `breakpoint` function ?

Comment: @guest271314 it says nothing

Comment: It does not mention the expected value.

Comment: At http://jsfiddle.net/hkqxswed/1/ , here, `console` logs `Uncaught ReferenceError: breakpoint is not defined ` `(index):46`

Comment: Why do you think you need this nesting? You should just move the constructor function outside, into that scope where you need it.

Comment: If something defined within a function would be accessible from outside, then would be no point in defining it inside in the first place.

Comment: @Bergi makes sense but I need it to be in my onResize event but I might be overcomplicating things.

Comment: @Asperger: why do you "need" it there? You cannot call it outside of the event handler then, before the event has happened.

Comment: @Bergi you are right. It doesnt make any sense keeping it inside. Just out of curiousity though. Is it technically possible? For example Kamus solution works or not? We did a check with console.log

Comment: I think im looking for something like this http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern

Comment: @Asperger: Yes, Kamus solution where `liquidFont` defines the function and assigns it to a global does work, but is a very fragile antipattern. What if you didn't call `liquidFont()` before you need `breakpoint`? What if you call it multiple times, even after already having constructed some `breakpoint` instances? Too many ways to get it wrong or cause arcane problems. Just move it outside.

Comment: @Asperger: A singleton? Yes, that seems like a better approach. But the code in the page you linked is horrible - you don't need this `getInstance()` method in JS at all. Just create the object using an object literal, and you're done. No "classes" should be involved in JS singletons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you can call `breakpoint` before to `liquidFont`.
The liquidFont function contain the code of breakpoint, if you never call it, breakpoint never will be defined.

But if you call first to `liquidFunction` and made to breakpoint global using a variable you can call it from anywhere

```
liquidFont();
var a = new breakpoint("start");
a.condition();
```

The example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hkqxswed/4/

if you really need call breakpoint from enywhere, you can create a js ["class"](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/), make it global and call from anywhere to create instances.

---

Maybe you need to refactor the liquidFont function and convert in a "static class", after this you will access to every property & method from anywhere:

```
var liquidFont : {
        settings : {
             start: true,
             compress: 100,
             minimum: 30,
             maximum: 120,
             animate: true,
             animationSpeed: 2000
             },
        cached : {
                 previousWidth: window.innerWidth
        },
        ...
        init : function(){  ... },
        breakpoint : { 
          condition : function(){  ...  }
        }
};
liquidFont.init();
liquidFont.breakpoint.condition();
```

Comment: Breakpoint is still undefined. I get that you are storing the function in a global but it still doesnt work.

Comment: where are you trying to call 'breakpoint' , i'm watching it working in the fiddle, inside the function 'called' , i wrote "console.log("called")", and is showing it without problems

Comment: kamus im trying to call it outside after the settings_liquidfont.

Comment: is not posibble to call in that part, you need to call it after the initialization of the element, you need to call liquidFont(); before to any call to breakpoint because in other way breakpoint never will be initialized

Comment: kamus but for example how is it possible with libraries such as greensock? you inlude their library in the head or before document and it works.

Comment: is because of the design pattern used , generally the libraries are like "object->properties/functions", and using singleton pattern. In that case everytime you use a reference the object exists, like jQuery, they create a global object and it can be referenced anywhere and all the methods is under the $/JQuery object

Comment: I understand now. So my pattern, eventhough I use objects is not exactly the same. Is this what you mean? http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern so then what I am actually trying to do is to use a singleton pattern in my script

Comment: Yes, the difference is because you are defining the "type" 'breakpoint' inside of your 'liquidFont' function that's the reason because you cant access before the initialization,never forget the scope in js functions , if you need to access from everywhere you can create a 'js class' and call anywhere:  http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: The article you showed me, isnt that something I already did? Except adding a return though. I could really need a real example such as with my code experiment but that would be little bit out of the scope of my original question. Im a very visual learner. Of course if you are so kind then feel free to do so, if not I will accept your question right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90172/discussion-between-kamus-and-asperger).